# Downloading IMAP/POP3 emails on a remote server?

Tags: debian, email, imap

I recently setup a Debian server on an old machine.

The purpose of this machine is to act as a blackbox of my life, and one of these goals is to backup all my emails.

Since there is no Xorg server or Wayland UI running I do not have the luxury of running a GUI desktop client like Thunderbird to sync with emails.

I tried configuring and using mutt, but that does not have any "automatic" mail syncing capabilities.

So my question is, what linux tools combined with some bash scripting could I use to pull off a sync tool (triggered remotely / or by CRON)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't just "mutt with automatic download" but a different category entirely. There are a few clients which are written *specifically* to download messages as a batch job and have no interactive UI.

Common tools used for this purpose are 'fetchmail' and 'getmail' (both of which can do IMAP as well as POP3), or 'mpop' (which is POP3-only).

It might be also possible to configure 'offlineimap' to download but never delete, although it's still meant as a sync tool and not a backup tool. (The difference is, if you delete a message in e.g. Gmail, offlineimap will also delete it locally while getmail won't.)